# Retrieving coordindates of PDF signature form fields in Java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, openpdf

I want to know how to retrieve the coordinates of signature form fields in a PDF using PDFBOX or OpenPDF. The input PDF contains an electronic signature which is digitally signed.

Looking forward for your Help.

Comment: Please ask 3 separate questions about Pdfbox, Openpdf and iText. Also, share your code. What have you tried.

Comment: In PDFBox call getRectangle() on a signature field.

Answer (score 1):

Placeholder means unsigned signature for me but you mentioned signed fields. But I write you both solutions for openPDF:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(...)
AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields();
//unsigned signatures
//ArrayList<String> al = fields.getBlankSignatureNames();
//signed signatures
ArrayList<String> al = fields.getSignatureNames();     

for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {

 String fieldName = al.get(i);
 float[] position = fields.getFieldPositions(fieldName);

 //assuming that signatures doesn't have several widgets. (like it can be for other fields)
 for(int i=0;i<position.length;i+=5){
    int pageNumber = (int) position[0];
    float lowerLeftX = position[1]; 
    float lowerLeftY = position[2];
    float upperRightX = position[3];
    float upperRightY = position[4];
    System.out.println("llx:"+lowerLeftX+" lly:"+lowerLeftY+" urx:"+upperRightX+" ury: "upperRightY);
 }
```